# Create a text file in an existing AWS S3 bucket using CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

Is it possible to create a text file in existing AWS S3 Bucket and write some data to the file using CloudFormation ?

Thank You

Answer (score 6):

You can't create any objects in buckets using CloudFormation with available resources.

However, you could create a [custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) based of a lambda function which would create desired text file.